# How can a ping response fail from my modem, but succeed from my ISP and Google DNS (beyond the modem) within the same timeframe?

Tags: ping

My network design is simple, it goes: "My Computer > Switch > Router > Modem > ISP". I am pinging the Switch, Router, Modem, ISP, and Google DNS at the same time. Occasionally, I am getting a request timeout response from my modem, but in the same timeframe the response from my ISP and Google's DNS is successful. The traffic must flow through the modem to get to my ISP and Google's DNS so how can the ping fail at the modem but still process the response upstream?

NOTE: When the ping fails from my modem, it is always exactly 30 fails. I am pinging every second, so it is always exactly 30 seconds.

Comment: Sadly, questions about home networking are off topic here.  You can try asking on [su].  Briefly, your modem is too busy handling traffic to respond to pings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your modem is too busy performing its primary tasks of forwarding packets to be able to do a low-priority task, such as generating an ICMP echo reply within the requester's timeout period.

The ICMP echo request to devices beyond the modem are simply packets to the modem, and its primary job is to forward those, while the ICMP request to the modem is a low-priority process of the modem, and it gets around to sending its reply when it has time, and that could be after the requester has expired its timeout.

Your modem is probably resource-constrained so it will be slow in responding to things like ICMP echo requests when it is busy forwarding packets.